# variable scope within Angular module

Tags: angularjs

A newbie question here: I'm working with Angular modules that are using dependency injection. If I inject $scope in module A and I do something like $scope.myVariable = 5, will $scope.myVariable be defined in module B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, scope are limited to a controller. So they will not reflect in another module.

Read more about it here: [Scopes in angularJs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I appreciate it.